# Does a JavaScript function that includes a jQuery selector belong inside the document.ready block?

Tags: jquery

I make a point of placing any user-fired functions outside the `$(document).ready(function () {` block even though (as below) they may include jQuery elements. With the proviso that the `PlaceOrder()` function will not be called before the document is loaded this code works correctly.

```
function PlaceOrder() {
    $("#BillMe").val($("#tbReferred").val());
    confirmOrderForm.submit();
}
```

Should I expect the general concept to always hold true - that jQuery elements are able to be correctly resolved by any function that is assured to not fire before the DOM is ready?

Comment: As long as the element is available when the function is called, you're good!

Comment: it doesn't belong inside of the DOMReady event unless the DOMReady event is required for it to find its target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not need to be in the ready function and the code will always be fine, except for elements that were created dynmaically and cant be used with `$.click()`.

For dynmacically created elements you would use delegate functions such as `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

No for user defined `function`'s such as this, it's necessary to include it in the ready block. If it would that would inhibit the usage quite a bit for external js files and so forth.